# How can I change the shape of a stroke? (after effects)

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

I have created a happy face with the mouth being made out of a single line of stroke. How can I change the shape of it to change into a sad face?

Comment: you have to assign several keyframes for 'position and rotation' of that very stroke from happy to sad transition or vice versa. before commenting I created one myself. and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing Shape of Stroke

Step 1 : Create a Stroke with Pen Tool
Step 2 : By Adding Node in Center with Pen Tool make it Curve as Smile Shape
Step 3 : Now in Path add the Keyframe to Start Animation
Step 4 : By Placing Cursor later change the Shape to Sad Face
Step 5 : It will work 
For More Details Please view this Video
https://youtu.be/ex9bPP542HM